# Override VS Normal Method

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, overriding

Can someone explain the difference between an override and just a normal method, and when an override should be used over the latter?

Every tutorial I have found uses words like "Polymorphism" and "Derived Classes" rather than just explain their application and when they should be used.

I am using C# in particular but an understanding of overrides as a concept would be very helpful.

Thanks for any input on the subject.

Comment: **[Overrides (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/overrides)** First sentence explains it. Not sure how appropriate or useful it is to "use layman's terms" if it is an OOP programming question and since this is not a tutorial site.

Comment: @Plutonix Then i suppose my second question is more applicable. When should an override be used vs just a method? Thanks.

Comment: It is used with inheritance.  If `Dog` inherits from `Animal` the `Speak` method cant be implemented on the base class because you cant know whether to bark, mew, chirp or growl.  So (one way) is to override `Speak` on the derived classes (Bird, Cat, Dog, Grumpkin, Snark) to implement the specific behavior.

Comment: Sidenote:  You likely ran into 'Overrides' from links related to Inheritance, so the context is important.  You cant override just any method because it might be fun

Comment: @Plutonix I swear I hadn't read your comment before I posted my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, overrides are for when you want to change the behavior of a method in a derived class. For example, say you had an `Animal.Speak()` method:

```
class Animal
{
    public virtual void Speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The animal makes random animal noises.");
    }
}
```

Now, if you had a specific type of animal, you'd want to override that `Speak()` method to make noises that that type of animal would make:

```
class Dog : Animal
{
    public override void Speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The dog barks.");
    }
}
```

Now if you make a Dog object and tell it to speak, it will bark. Now let's consider if you had a Cat class but didn't override the `Speak()` method:

```
class Cat : Animal
{
}
```

If you had this code:

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
Animal cat = new Cat();

dog.Speak();
cat.Speak();
```

You'd see this:

```
The dog barks.
The animal makes random animal noises.
```

Comment: You’d see the same output without overriding and simply hiding. A more appropiate example would be: `Animal dog = ...; Animal cat = ...;`

Comment: @InBetween Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding occurs when you make a method/function/subroutine that has the same name as another function, but has different functionality. One prominent example is the Equals method. This method can be overridden for a custom object to return your concept of equality. For example, if you have a Person object and decide that 2 Persons are equal when they have the same name, you could override the existing Equals method to return whether or not 2 Persons have the same name. Good luck!

Comment: Telling someone to google and/or linking to another SO post is not considered and answer.  A comment at best

Comment: This could be a good answer if you format it nicer and go more in-depth with a couple examples, especially with code.

Comment: don't mix OVERRIDE with OVERLOAD

Answer (score 0):

For example, if there is an predefined class which has a method "ABC" and you want to change its behavior. In that case you have to write the keyword override before the method ABC that you want to change from its default to what you really want to have. Simple words use override when you have to change already existing method. Do not use override when you are creating a new method of any object which already does not exists.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by "overriden" method? 
There are two options:

1. Override virtual methods in subclasses. Here "method overriding" is a part of polymorphism - one of the concept of object-oriented programming.

For instance, here you have a base class A with some virtual methods:

```
public class A
{
    public void Method1() {}
    public virtual void Method2() {}
    public virtual void Method3() {}
}
```

If you create class B, which is derived from A you will have an opportunity to override virtual methods in such case:

```
public class B : A 
{
    public override void Method2() {}
    public override void Method3() {}
}
```

In such way you change your base functionality from class A by your new functionality from class B.
So, when you call method from instance of class B , you will get functionality from overriden method in class B:

```
B instanceB = new B();
instanceB.Method2();
```

2. Override method signature. Here you are able to have multiple methods with same name, but with different signatures.

For example, you have such class with 3 methods, which have one name TestMethod, but there are different signatures (different input and output parameter types):

```
public class TestClass
{
    public void TestMethod() {}
    public int TestMethod(int value) {}
    public string TestMethod(int value) {}
}
```

Comment: Your first example would work with hiding just as well. Your second example is *overloading*, not overriding.

Comment: Your second option refers to overloading, which is different from overriding. The third TestMethod would have to have a different parameter type. Overloading doesn't permit you to only change the return type. The compiler wouldn't be able to tell which method you're referring to.

Comment: Why first example is hiding? If I would use new keyword in method signature of derived class, so in this case it would be hiding, but I used override keyword instead. Concerning 2d option I agree with you, I thought it was named as overriding too.

Comment: The reason he says that is because what you have shown doesn't provide anything extra beyond what hiding already does. Changing this line of code shows overriding better `A instanceB = new B(); instanceB.Method2();`. You would not be able to do this with just hiding. At least that is my understanding, I am not an expert on this subject.

Comment: thank you guys, will improve my knowledges to give correct answers.